# tcpdf cant draw dasharry line in svg file

Tags: php, svg, tcpdf

I have a svg String that in it I draw a dasharry Line I want draw it in a pdf file with tcpdf library.when I use px unit in svg String all of things is ok but I need my unit be Cm and when I change Unit to Cm it draw a Line instead of dasharry Line.I search web but I cant find any things that help me.

My svg code

```
<svg   height="29.7cm"  width="21cm"  viewBox="0 0 210 297" >
<g     style="stroke-width:10;stroke:red;fill:none">
<path  style="stroke-dasharray:10,20;" d="M 10 10 10 600" />
</g>
</svg>
```

and My php code

```
 $pdf->ImageSVG('@'.$g,$x=0,$y=0,$w='',$h='',$link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false,false);
```

Comment: Your code works for me. It's displayed with a dashed red line.

Comment: it dont work with tcpdf .tcpdf draw a red line instead of dashary red line.@MattRaines

Comment: It works fine for me. I have the TCPDF version that's bundled with Ubuntu 16.04, version 6.0.093+dfsg-1ubtuntu1. Here's a screenshot of the output of your code sample. http://imgur.com/70Fs8RZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found My answer .should replace

```
$dash_string .= sprintf('%F', $this->getHTMLUnitToUnits($v, 0, $this->svgunit, false));
```

with

```
$dash_string .= sprintf('%F', $v);
```

in `SetLineStyle` Method of `TCPDF` Class,